# No list of all open Safari windows/tabs on other devices in iOS 15.0 or Safari 15

Tags: ios, icloud, safari, mobile-safari, ipados

I used to be able to access all open windows on my Mac on my iPhone (or iPad) and vice versa (via the tabs button). Unfortunately, ever since I installed Safari 15.0 on my Mac and iOS 15 (and iPad OS 15), that doesn't seem to be possible anymore.

I also made sure that Safari is on in iCloud on all my devices. Was this feature dismissed by Apple or is it a bug? Are there ways to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They moved it. When you tap in the url input, the content of the screen no longer shows the web site you were on, but instead shows your “Favorites.” You can scroll down on that screen to see other categories of saved pages, like your reading list, and at the bottom you’ll find tabs from other devices. The name of a device will be the heading, and you can tap on that heading to choose which device you want to see the tabs from. [image]