# How do I troubleshoot the Safari tabs iCloud sync failure?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, safari, catalina

Running Catalina 10.15.7 (MacBook Air) and iOS 15.6 (iPhone 12). I followed the directions from Apple:

1. On iOS iCloud settings, turn on Safari
2. On macOS iCloud settings, turn on Safari.
3. Signed in to same iCloud account on both.

As far as I tell, that's all that's needed. Yet I can't see that the tabs are shared.

Comment: In either direction?

Comment: @MarcWilson yes either direction.

Comment: How do you figure out that the sync does not work? Exactly where do you look in Safari either on your Mac or iPhone to see the shared tabs? I am asking because the information provided in the "[Set up and use iCloud Tabs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202530)" Apple Support article about where to look for shared tabs is actually obsolete if this is how you are checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to circumvent this problem, at least on your Mac, by asking Safari on your Mac to show you the web pages open in Safaris in your other Apple devices through the iCloud Tabs[image]button. However, you may first need to make the button available.

To make the iCloud Tabs button available, Choose View > Customize Toolbar from Safari's menu and drag the button to the Safari toolbar. Once this is done and assuming you have activated, as you have described in your post, the Safari option under iCloud in all devices you wish to share the open webpages among, just click on the iCloud Tabs button in the Safari toolbar and you should see the open webpages in your other devices.

See the "[Customize the Safari browser window on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/customize-the-safari-window-ibrw1012/13.0/mac/10.15)" Apple Support webpage for more, if necessary, on customizing the Safari toolbar in macOS Catalina.

Comment: That worked! Whatever it was that I read on the Apple support page on how to do this did not work, and never mentioned anything about the iCloud button, far as I could find.

Comment: Happy to hear that iCloud Tabs button has helped but note that this is an extra convenience, not the normal way Safari iCloud tabs is supposed to work. I suggest you also check out [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/427918/359458) to a question similar to yours. Though the answer applied to macOS Big Sur by default at the time, I think it is still helpful for Monterey and might also be helpful for Catalina.